# What is an adjective for a person who perceives everything and everyone as dumb?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

Perhaps a word that is a little less than "nihilistic"

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

supercilious and haughty are the two that spring to mind.

Comment: I'm thinking of Blasé, playing more off "nihilistic" than "dumb" since we are not just talking about people, but "everything".

Comment: Perhaps but if we go down that route I should recommend the more familiar blithe; to which blase is likely related.

Comment: Not sure if blithe is more familiar; it isn't to me. And "Blithe" doesn't have a cool jazz standard by Ella Fitzgerald ;)

Comment: Blithe is of a plain Saxon (old-english) origin and has been in use for centuries whereas blasé has only been in use since the late 19th century and is a french borrowing. So therefore blithe would be preferable to me and most writers over blasé. And unfortunately I am not versed in jazz references :(

Comment: To me *blithe* is uncaring, perhaps thoughtless and casual, but not judgmental of other people. Thus, not even thinking about whether they’re dumb.